# Large memory footprint caused by CoreGraphics in Instruments

Tags: iphone, objective-c, instruments

I'm doing some performance testing in Instruments on the device for an iPhone application that is in development.

I'm seeing that the two largest chunks of memory that are been allocated aren't through any of my custom methods (to my knowledge).

Screenshot 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFFux.png

The background to the application is that it is an application, which uses CoreData to consume a web service and store/display the data. Linked images are then downloaded (async), resized to a smaller size within the app and the new image is then displayed. I originally thought that the images were the problem but testing the app in offline mode without the data or images been downloaded and the large Malloc of 4.5mb still appears.

I'm struggling to identify the source of the memory footprint and ultimately try to reduce/remove it through an AutoRelease pool or another means.

Comment: Sorry the second screenshot is probably the most important with the call tree but could only post screenshot: http://imgur.com/ZL8JP

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to diagnose memory issues from a few screenshots. Your best bet is to learn a bit more about instruments and memory profiling so you can determine for yourself what the problem is. I *highly* recommend watching the [WWDC 2010 session 310 - Advanced Memory Analysis with Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.4088575739). It really helped me to learn where the problems in my app were.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and I've followed it. It's helped me find the first part of identifying when it's getting added to the heap but it appears in Instruments as a <non-object> so unsure how to manage that. Any ideas?

Comment: What is your total live bytes in the app? Are you leaking any memory? Any zombies identified?